# Howto update Perl v5.8.8 for git?

Tags: perl, git, qt

I have following Problem.

I want to build Qt5 by my own, to be able to use it with Visual Studio 2012. I followed the instructions in the [Qt Wiki](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building-Qt-5-from-Git#0b79795d3efc95b9976c7c5b933afce2).

My problem is that when I try to call init-repository

```
perl init-repository
```

I get following error:

```
Hint: Make sure that Perl is added to the path in front of git since that ships an outdated version (Perl 5.8), which will cause the scripts to fail.
```

This is because the with git shipped perl version is 5.8.8. It doesn't matter, that I have the newest version installed.

Can someone tell me how to update my perl version inside git, to be able to build Qt5?

Regards

Comment: It looks like the intent is to have a newer Perl installed, and make sure that is on the path before Git so that the newer Perl installation is found. Quoting the Qt wiki:

`We recommend creating a command prompt that provides the build environment (see the Qt Creator README [qt.gitorious.org] ). In this environment, Python (e.g. Active Python 2.7 later) and Perl (e.g. Active State Perl 5.12 or later) should be in the PATH.`

Comment: My path, Active Perl and Python are right. It's the git build in perl that have to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are working on Windows, I assume with some recent version of `msysgit`.

If you are using the shell that comes with `msysgit`, then it is likely that the shell has modified your `PATH` variable to put `/bin` ahead of `/c/path/to/new/perl`.  You can check this by opening the shell and running `echo $PATH` or even `which perl`.

To make the shell use you 'new' perl, you can try the following:

`export PATH=/c/path/to/new/perl:$PATH`

Comment: I've tried it first with the Git Shell and now with msysGit and MinGW. Exact the same error. The Path variable should be right:
C:\Python33\;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd